# How to add a size attribute to shopping cart item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I built a working shopping cart system the other day using Ruby on Rails, and with the guidance of following a tutorial.  Now I would like to modify the existing shopping cart item to incorporate the size of a particular item being placed in the cart.

I created a migration file to add a size column to the Products table, and then I started modifying `CartItem` class, and the `Cart` class files respectively.

```
class CartItem
    attr_reader :product_id, :quantity, :size

    def initialize product_id, quantity = 1, size
        @product_id = product_id
        @quantity = quantity
        @size = size
    end

    def increment
        @quantity = @quantity + 1
    end

    def product
        Product.find product_id
    end

    def total_price
        # puts "Hello cart_item"
        product.price * quantity
    end
end

class Cart
    attr_reader :items

    def self.build_from_hash hash
        items = if hash["cart"] then
            hash["cart"]["items"].map do |item_data|
                CartItem.new item_data["product_id"], item_data["quantity"], item_data["size"]
            end
        else
            []
        end

        new items
    end

    def initialize items = []
        @items = items
    end

    def add_item product_id, size
        item = @items.find { |item| item.product_id == product_id
                                    item.size == size }
        if item
            item.increment
        else
            @items << CartItem.new(product_id, size)
        end
    end

    def empty?
        @items.empty?
    end

    def count
        @items.length
    end

    def serialize
        items = @items.map do |item| 
            { 
                "product_id" => item.product_id, 
                "quantity" => item.quantity,
                "size" => item.size 
            } 
        end

        {
            "items" => items
        }
    end

    def total_price(shipping_price = 0)
        # puts "Hello cart"
        @items.inject(0) { |sum, item| sum + item.total_price } + shipping_price
    end
end
```

However, I'm getting the following error,

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your add_item method should be into two parameter, but your params is hash can't use `params[:id, :size]` replace `params[:id], params[:size]` it work.